# Least upper and greatest lower bounds

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $n\ge 3$ be an arbitrarily fixed integer. Take all the possible finite sequences $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ of positive numbers. Find the least upper and the greatest lower bounds of the set of numbers
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}
$$
where we put $a_{n+1}=a_1$ and $a_{n+2}=a_2$.

I've been struggling to solve this problem from the book "Problems in Mathematical Analysis I" from W.J. Kaczor and M.T. Nowak but I've given up. As the book provides a solution I've checked it, but there's something I don't understand:

[image]

When it says $\textit{To this end we take } a_k=t^k,t>0$, what result is this? Where can I find it?

Another question: how to get
$$
\dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le 1-\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{s}-\dfrac{a_{k+2}}{s}
$$
I guess it's using the fact that
$$
\dfrac{a}{b}\le \dfrac{c}{d} \implies \dfrac{a}{b}\le \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}
$$
is my assumption right? If not I don't see how to obtain the upper bound either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a result.  That's a just saying "let's take a certain sequence where $a_k = t^k$".  He could just as well have said "let's take the sequence where $a_k = 5*k + 3$" except that wouldn't have helped us in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  He's not saying "Let's take a previous result where we proved $a_k = t^k$". He's saying "Let's take the sequence where $a_k:= t^k$".  It is just one possible sequence.

2)
$s = a_1 + ........  + a_n$ so

$\dfrac {a_k}s = \dfrac {a_k}{a_1 + a_2 + .... + a_n} \le \dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}$

because $s \ge a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}$

$\dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}= \dfrac {a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2} -a_{k+1} - a_{k+2}}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}=$

$ 1 - \dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}- \dfrac{a_{k+2}}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le$

$ 1 - \dfrac{a_{k+1}}{s}- \dfrac{a_{k+2}}{s}$

=====

Outline of his proof.

1) Prove for all $\{a_k\}$ that $\dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}} \ge 1$. So $1$ is a lower bound.

2) Prove for all $\{a_k\}$ that $\dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}} \le n-2$. So $n-2$ is an upper bound.

3) Show that if we take the sequences $\{a_{k,t}\} = \{t^k\}$ then

3a) $$\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \sum \dfrac{a_{k,t}}{a_{k,t}+a_{k+1,t}+a_{k+2,t}}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}[ \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\dfrac{t^k}{t^k+t^{k+1}+t^{k+2}} + \dfrac{t^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}+t^{n}+t} + \dfrac{t^{n}}{t^{n}+t+t^2}]=1$$ so $1$ is not just a lower bound it is the greatest lower bound.

3b)$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \sum \dfrac{a_{k,t}}{a_{k,t}+a_{k+1,t}+a_{k+2,t}}=\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}[ \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\dfrac{t^k}{t^k+t^{k+1}+t^{k+2}} + \dfrac{t^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}+t^{n}+t} + \dfrac{t^{n}}{t^{n}+t+t^2}]=n-2$$ so $n-2$ is not just an upper bound it is the least lower bound.

Comment: And why does he take that sequence? What's the point in doing so?

Comment: I don't know.  You cut off the proof before he finished and it's too earlier for me to try to figure it out.  .... If you wanted to know that, that should have been your third question..... If you include the rest of the solution I'll eyeball it and help you figure it out but I'm too tired to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Oh.... He's probably going to show that by taking the proper values of $t$ he can find a value of $t$ that has the sum equal to $1$ (or has a limit equal to 1) and another value of $t$ that has a sum (or limit) equal to $n-2$.  So that $1$ and $n-2$ aren't just upper and lower bounds, they are inf and sup.

Comment: To show that $\inf =1$ you must show 1) $\sum \ge 1$ for all {$a_k$}.  He did that.  And that either 2a) there is an {$a_k$} where $\sum = 1$ or that 2b) for any $d > 1$ then there is an {$a_k$} where $\sum < d$.  I'll bet anything he will show there is a $t$ where $a_k = t^k$ will yield 2a) or 2b).... Same thing for proving $\sup = n-2$.

Comment: Ah... and I see how he will do it.  Each $\frac {t^k}{t^{k} + t^{k+1} + t^{k+2}}= \frac 1{1 + t + t^2}$ (except the last two) so $\sum = (n-2)\times \frac 1{1+t + t^2}+ \frac 1{1+t^{1-n} + t^{-n}} + \frac 1{1+t^{-n} + t^{-n-1}}$ so $t\to 0$, $\sum \to (n-2)*1 + 0 + 0=n-2$ and $t \to \infty$, $\sum \to (n-2)*0 + \frac 12 + \frac 12=1$.

Comment: That's exactly what he does.

Answer (score 0):

1.) That's not a result, that's just a certainly allowed way to pick specific values of the $a_n$ (just with less of those pesky degrees of freedom).

2.) No. Simply apply $\sum_{k=1}^n$ to 
$$\frac{a_k}s\le \frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le1-\frac{a_{k+1}}2-\frac{a_{k+1}}s $$
to obtain 
$$1=\frac ss=\frac{\sum a_k}s\le \sum\frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le\sum1-\frac{\sum a_{k+1}}2-\frac{\sum a_{k+1}}s=n-2 $$